# Editing the content of ASP.NET Control 

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Below is the content of my Default.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        WELCOME     
    </h2>
    <p id="exampleId">
        I want to edit here
    </p>

</asp:Content>
```

I want to be able to find the control with ID "exampleID", and write something into it using c#.

Comment: Make it into a `runat="server"` control.

Comment: What about using one of the controls provided by asp.net? like `<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="exampleId" />` which can be accessed by `exampleId.Text = "Hello, World!";`

Comment: Please do not include C# in Title just tag it as C# Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> runat = "server" was missing in the tag to access it from code behind.

**HTML**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        WELCOME     
    </h2>
    <p id="exampleId" runat = "server">
        I want to edit here
    </p>

</asp:Content>
```

---

**C# Code**

```
exampleId.InnerText = "Your text";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have few options here:

1. Add runat="server"
2. Add asp.net server side control "literal" inside p

   ```
   <p>
       <asp:Literal ID="exampleId" runat="server" />
   </p>
   ```

   Don't use Label for that, as this will render with additional SPAN, which you don't want.

Hope it helps.